# Position <div> on top

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have an area on a page that uses  with overflow. In side that div a have content with a few links and a few hidden divs. When a link is clicked, a hidden div is shown. In FF the div appears like intended: above everything else, in IE, however it appears above the content inside the div with overflow, but not above the overflow. How can I fix that?

Here's an example of my code:

```
<style>
.hiddenDiv {
    position:absolute;
    zIndex:9999;
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
<div style="overflow-y: auto; border: 1px solid #ccc; height: 200px; width: 300px">
    some content here
    <div class="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">more content here</div>
</div>
```

i think this is some sort of IE specific issue.

Comment: Do you have a link to a working copy? Would be good to see what is intended and what is broken...

Comment: Unfortunately the page is behind a firewall... I am afraid I have some conflicts with other styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your page is rendered in quirks mode..

Do you have a doctype declared in  your page ?

example that works fine unless IE is put in quirks mode (*then it exhibits the behavior you describe*): http://www.jsfiddle.net/UtKYn/1/

Comment: Yes, it works when it is just this code. I think I have some conflicts with other styles. Not sure how to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`* { zoom: 1; }`

Though it's not advised to use the `*` selector, so try to narrow it down a little.
Also, consider `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```

above code for the div that is indented.

Comment: No, it's not indented, it's hidden and  when I click a particular element it becomes visible and floats above.